# JBoss 7 module unresolved dependencies

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I got a couple of .jar, say EasyEjbNode1.jar and EasyEjbNode2.jar. EasyEjbNode1.jar wants to invoke a session bean from EasyEjbNode2.jar, which has been, previously, succesfully deployed. Here is the code of the session bean, in EasyEjbNode1, who want to invoke the session bean from EasyEjbNode2:
`

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import edu.pezzati.node2.RemoteNode2;

@Stateless
public class SessionNode1 implements RemoteNode1 {
@EJB(name="java:global/SessionNode2!edu.pezzati.node2.RemoteNode2")

RemoteNode2 rn2;

    @Override
    public String getNodeName() {
        return "node1 ";
    }

    @Override
    public String getRemoteNodeName() {
        return "node1 "+rn2.getNodeName();
    }
}
```

`
and here is the content of EasyEjbNode1.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: deployment.EasyEjbNode2.jar
```

Sadly, something goes wrong:

```
10:40:04,725 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EasyEjbNode1.jar".INSTALL: org.jbos.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EasyEjbNode1.jar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "EasyEjbNode1.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
    JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'edu.pezzati.node2.RemoteNode2' for binding java:global/EasyEjbNode2/SessionNode2!edu.pezzati.node2.RemoteNode2
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:249)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:155)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed by myself. The problem was just a stupid mistake. Replace

```
    @EJB(name="java:global/SessionNode2!edu.pezzati.node2.RemoteNode2")
```

with

```
    @EJB(lookup="java:global/SessionNode2!edu.pezzati.node2.RemoteNode2")
```

this works for me. I can succesfully invoke SessionNode2's services from SessionNode1, which is placed in a different jar.

Comment: today I found the same mistake by someone else at SO itself and the same rectification done.

Comment: @KNU glad to hear I'm not alone.